# AngularJS, using ng-show breaks select2's layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2

I'm creating a dynamic page that loads a lot of filters from the server. I want to show those filters only when all server side calls are done. For that, I'm using a simple `true/false` variable (`ng-show="filtersDone"`, 11th row).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-1 table_padding_content">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                <span><strong> Planning - Details </strong></span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row" ng-show="filtersDone">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
                                <label for="searchFilters.year" class="control-label">Year</label>
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilters.year" ng-options="y as y for y in yearsList"></select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                <label for="searchFilters.dealer" class="control-label">Dealers</label>
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilters.dealer" ng-options="dealer.ID as dealer.Name for dealer in dealers"><option></option></select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                <label for="searchFilters.planningStatus" class="control-label">Planning Status</label>
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilters.planningStatus">
                                    <option></option>
                                    <option value="1">Started</option>
                                    <option value="2">Compiled</option>
                                    <option value="3">Archived</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label for="searchFilters.buildingType" class="control-label">Building Type</label>
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilters.buildingType" id="select2_buildingType" name="searchFilters.buildingType"
                                        multiple="multiple" ng-options="item.ID as item.Name for item in buildingTypes">
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                <label for="searchFilters.buildingCategory" class="control-label">Building Category</label>
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="searchFilters.buildingCategory" id="select2_buildingCategory" name="searchFilters.buildingCategory" 
                                        multiple="multiple" ng-options="item.ID as item.Category for item in buildingCategories">
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <label class="control-label" style="width: 100%">&nbsp;</label>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clean()">Clean</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the part of the controller for filters. `$scope.filtersDone` is setted to `false` at the beginning of the function, then i call all the server side functions to get all select values and then, when evertything is done, i set `$scope.filtersDone` to `true` (28th row). 
I thought the problem could be that i was initializing select2 select before the  `$scope.filtersDone = true;` but it doesn't change if I do it before or after.

```
$scope.init = function () {
  $scope.filtersDone = false;

  apiCustomService.defaultYear.get(function (res) {
    $scope.currentYear = res.value;

    $scope.yearsList = [];
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      $scope.yearsList.push(currentYear - i);
    }

    apiCustomService.dealersGet.get(function(dealers) {
      $scope.dealers = dealers;
      apiCustomService.operaType.get(function(buildingTypes) {
        $scope.buildingTypes = buildingTypes;
        apiCustomService.operaCategory.get(function(buildingCategories) {
          $scope.buildingCategories = buildingCategories;
          apiCustomService.inspectionTypes.get(function(inspectionTypes) {
            $scope.inspectionTypes = inspectionTypes;
            apiCustomService.getListOfValues.get(function(listOfValues) {
              $scope.listOfValues = listOfValues;
              apiCustomService.getAllBuildingCodes.get(function(buildingCodes) {
                $scope.buildingCodes = buildingCodes.codes;

                $scope.searchFilters = {year: $scope.currentYear};

                $scope.filtersDone = true;

                jQuery('#select2_buildingType').select2({
                  multiple: true,
                  placeholder: " ",
                  allowClear: true,
                  language: 'it'
                });

                jQuery('#select2_buildingCategory').select2({
                  multiple: true,
                  placeholder: " ",
                  allowClear: true,
                  language: 'it'
                });
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

$scope.init();
```

If i don't use `ng-show="filtersDone"`, this is the (correct) situation:

[image]

But if i use it, this is the situation (layout breaks down only for select2 components):

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ng-show is set to false, the element is not available in the page to be manipulated, because angular hides it using CSS: "display: none !important"

So instead of ng-show, you can use a class or style directive to hide the element via the usage of either CSS visibility or opacity rules.

This ensures that the element is being rendered in the page even though it is not visible.

basically replace this:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="filtersDone">
```

with this:

```
<div class="row" ng-style="{'opacity': filtersDone ? '1' : '0' }">
```

Comment: Ooooh i thought `ng-if` does that, and that `ng-show` initialize the component in the dom but didnt't show it....a misunderstanding in my knowledge, thanks for that.
And it works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: This is confusing at times. ng-if doesnt even render the markup in the view, while ng-show hides it with brute forced css.

Comment: That means ng-show initialize the component only when the expression is true...that mean i should have initialize select2 within the ng-show function to make it work...but opacity doesnt force me to initialize piece by piece and that's cool